# Using "DllImport" in a multithreaded C# Application

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
    static void manageThreads(string user, string pass)
    {
        Sessions sess = new Session();
        sess.beginSession(user, pass);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string user = "blah";
        string pass = "blah";
        int count = 10;
        int initial = 0;

        Thread[] sessions = new Thread[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            sessions[i] = new Thread(() => manageThreads(user + (i + initial), pass + (i + initial)));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            sessions[i].Start();
        }
    }
```

(I know this is messy) 
but within the session code I have something along the lines of:

```
    [DllImport("IdlerLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int startSession(String user, String pass);

    public void beginSession(string User, string Pass)
    {
        startSession(User, Pass);}
```

This then passes a user and pass to a C++ DLL that starts a login session,
The issue now is that it seems to only call the function on one thread, is it possible to have the same function run on multiple threads at the same time?

Many Thanks
James

Comment: Though it's possible can lead to unexpected behavior. Make sure your DLL is thread safe.

Comment: That is very unlikely.  The much more likely mishap is that your program terminates before the C++ code can do anything useful.  Add Console.ReadLine() and try again.  If that doesn't help then use a telephone to talk to the author of the DLL.  Non-zero odds he will tell you that his code is not thread-safe.